# anyone can help me, how can i save and close this section?

Tags: virtualbox

How can I save and close this section?
I have to tried to close this section but it still like that

[image]

Comment: you're using `vim`.  hit "escape" then type in `:wq`.  Unless you're asking how to get out of the virtualbox environment?

Answer (score 0):

you would need to press the <kbd>Right Control</kbd> button, then it will release the mouse so you can click outside. If you are in a laptop then it could  be <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> + <kbd>Right Control</kbd> or <kbd>Alt Fn</kbd> + <kbd>Right Control</kbd>.